# python 3: how do I create two different classes that operate on the same data?

Tags: python, oop, single-responsibility-principle

I have a class that looks something like the following:

```
# Class violates the Single Responsibility Principle
class Baz:
    data = [42]
    def do_foo_to_data(self):
        # call a dozen functions that do complicated stuff to data

    def do_bar_to_data(self):
        # call other functions that do different stuff to data
```

I want to break it into two separate classes because it violates the SRP. The functions called by `do_foo_to_data()` are completely distinct from those called by `do_bar_to_data()`. Yet they must operate on the same `data`.

I've come up with a bunch of solutions, but they're all ugly. Is there a way to do this cleanly, preferably in Python 3 (though 2.7 is OK too)?

The best of my "solutions" is below:

```
# I find this hard to read and understand
class Baz:
    data = [42]

    def create_foo(self):
        return Baz.Foo()

    def create_bar(self):
        return Baz.Bar()


    class Foo:
        def do_foo_to_data(self):
            # call foo functions


    class Bar:
        def do_bar_to_data(self):
            # call bar functions
```

Note: It's *not* essential to me that the `data` member be a class member.
I only expect to create one instance of `Baz`; but I didn't want to ask two questions in one post and start a discussion about singletons.

Comment: Without the actual requirements, it is too hard to comment. Separation of concerns and SRP doesn't mean your class cannot have multiple methods. In your "solution", Baz still has the same problem as in original. Maybe thinking of the problem as a Model-View-Controller would help. Have one class that manages the data (Model) and other classes that do the manipulations / operations (Controllers). If needed you can throw a class on top to represent the results (View).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an elegant solution. You better **pass a reference** to the object you want them to operate on. So something like:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def do_foo_to_data(self):
        #...
        self.data[0] = 14
        pass

class Bar:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def do_bar_to_data(self):
        #...
        self.data.append(15)
        pass
```

(I added sample manipulations like `self.data[0] = 14` and `self.data.append(15)`)

And now you construct the data. For instance:

```
data = [42]
```

Next you construct a `Foo` and a `Bar` and **pass a reference to `data`** like:

```
foo = Foo(data)
bar = Bar(data)
```

`__init__` is what most programming languages call the *constructor* and as you have seen in the first fragment, it requires an additional parameter `data` (in this case it is a reference to our constructed `data`).

and then you can for instance call:

```
foo.do_foo_to_data()
```

which will set `data` to `[14]` and

```
bar.do_bar_to_data()
```

which will result in `data` being equal to `[14,15]`.

Mind that you **cannot state** `self.data = ['a','new','list']` or something equivalent in `do_foo_to_data` or `do_bar_to_data` because **this would change the reference to a new object**. Instead you could for instance `.clear()` the list, and append new elements to it like:

```
def do_foo_to_data(self): #alternative version
    #...
    self.data.clear()
    self.data.append('a')
    self.data.append('new')
    self.data.append('list')
```

Finally to answer your remark:

> preferably in Python 3 (though 2.7 is OK too)?

The technique demonstrated is almost universal (meaning it is available in *nearly* every programming language). So this will work in both [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) and [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7).

Comment: Yes I see this as an MVC type break down. Your "Model" in this case is a list object and the Foo and Bar are "Controllers".

Comment: @RobertB: Well I think that's the most elegant way to do it since you can introduce other "model"s and controllers as well whereas the code in the question only has one "model" and thus is quite limited. Usually it is not a good idea to make many *singleton* objects since all of a sudden you can change your mind and have to introduce more.

Comment: I agree. Rather than have singleton objects, the OP should consider whether he needs classes at all, or if his manipulations are really just functions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 4):

Why do you even need a class for that? All you want is two separated functions which do some job on some data.

```
data = [42]

def foo(data):
    data.append('sample operation foo')

def bar(data):
    data.append('sample operation bar')
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out the distinct groups of functionality to separate mix-in classes:

```
class Foo:
    """Mixin class.

    Requires self.data (must be provided by classes extending this class).
    """
    def do_foo_to_data(self):
        # call a dozen functions that do complicated stuff to data

class Bar:
    """Mixin class.

    Requires self.data (must be provided by classes extending this class).
    """
    def do_bar_to_data(self):
        # call other functions that do different stuff to data

class Baz(Foo, Baz):
    data = [42]
```

This relies on Python's duck-typing behavior. You should only apply the `Foo` and `Bar` mix-ins to classes that actually provide `self.data`, like the `Baz` class here does.

This might be suitable where certain classes are by convention required to provide certain attributes anyway, such as customized view classes in Django. However, when such conventions aren't already in place, you might not want to introduce new ones. It's too easy to miss the documentation and then have `NameError`s at runtime. So let's make the dependency explicit, rather than only documenting it. How? With a mix-in for the mix-ins!

```
class Data:
    """Mixin class"""
    data = [42]

class Foo(Data):
    """Mixin class"""
    def do_foo_to_data(self):
        # call a dozen functions that do complicated stuff to data

class Bar(Data):
    """Mixin class"""
    def do_bar_to_data(self):
        # call other functions that do different stuff to data

class Baz(Foo, Baz):
    pass
```

Whether this is appropriate for your use-case is difficult to say at this level of abstraction. As [RayLuo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41903514/674064) shows, you might not need classes at all. Instead, you could put the different groups of functions into different modules or packages, to organize them.